# Error: "Unused argument N" Why is it giving me this error?

Tags: r, math, syntax-error

Here is my code,

```
BinAmerPut <- function(S0,R,sigmaA,sigmaB,K,T,N) {
   Cn <- rep(0, N+1)
   tempC <- 0
   C0 <- 0
   sigma <- (sigmaA+sigmaB)/2
   Dt <- T/N
   D <- exp(-R*Dt)
   a <- exp(-R*Dt)+exp((R*Dt)+ (Dt*sigma^2))/2
   d <- a-sqrt(a^2-1)
   u <- 1/d
   p <- (exp(R*Dt)-d)/(u-d)
   q <- (1-p)
   for (n in N:1){
       for (j in 1:(n+1)){
           if (n == N){
               Cn[j] <- max((S0*(u^(j-1)*(d^(N-(j-1))))) - K, 0)
           }
           if (n < N){
               tempC <- D*(p*Cn[j+1]+q*Cn[j])
               Cn[j] <- max(S0*(u^(j-1))*(d^(N-(j-1)))-K, tempC)
           }
       }
     }
     C0 <- max(S0-K,D*(p*Cn[2]+q*Cn[1]))
     return(C0)
}
S0 <- 100
R <- 0.03
T <- 1.0
N <- 4
K <- 100

BinAmerPut(S0, R, 0.1, 0.25, K, T, N)
```

Perhaps I am missing something which I can't seem to find.? Eventually, my goal is to then add the bisection theorem in a while loop.

Thanks!

Comment: `object 'sigmaC' not found`

Comment: if I do `sigmaC <- 0.5`, then I get `q * Cn[j] (from #18) : non-numeric argument to binary operator`

Comment: This suggests that you don't have a completely self-contained and reproducible function going on here. Some of these errors may only be apparent when you start in a fresh R instance (no loading of `.Rdata`) and try *just this code*.

Comment: @R2evans Thanks for noticing! Changed that to just "sigma" But I still get the same error

Comment: also you did not intialize the variable `q`, which makes R to perform a multiplication of `q` or `quit()` function with the value of Cn[j].

Comment: What do you think about `q`? For me, it is a *function* (to quit R). I stress again that your function is relying on variables outside of its scope. *This is a problem* that will make troubleshooting the math of your function **very difficult**. I wish there was a way to tell a function to never reach outside scope for variables, but ...

Comment: Sorry! I'm new to R and have been trying to understand it as best as I can! I just initialized it to q<- (1-p)

Comment: [edit] your question and update it, please. Comments are easily skipped by readers, and when there are many, the interface will hide some.

Comment: When I make those corrections (`sigmaC` to `sigma`, and `q <- (1-p)`), I get no error. Instead, I get `63.1753`. This might be that *"difficult troubleshooting"* I mentioned earlier.

Comment: @R2evans what did you mean by "Some of these errors may only be apparent when you start in a fresh R instance (no loading of .Rdata) and try just this code"? I'd like to try what you suggested.

Comment: I mean this: if you have `q` defined (as `(1-p)`) in your global environment, then when you run this function without internally instantiating that variable, it works just fine. But for the rest of us (who do not see what is in your global environment), we get the error. The fact that I see an error about objects not found and you do not see them suggests that your function is not self-contained. If you define the function in a fresh/clean R instance (nothing pre-defined at all!) and run it with the arguments you provide here, does it work?

Comment: This is not intended as condescending or soap-boxing, it's a common "problem" with new programmers. (In my opinion, "most" analysts and people studying to be analysts are really not good programmers.) One of the hard parts of learning how to program in a new language is troubleshooting when (not if) things go wrong. What I'm suggesting is one technique to minimize complications. (A draconian step would be to periodically `rm(list=ls())`, re-`source` all files, and try again ... unfortunately if you forgot something, it's nuked and gone forever, so I don't recommend doing it that way.)

Comment: So basically rewriting this code from scratch (but I can copy it word for word as long as I re-type it in a new R file)? *** This was regarding your first comment ***

Comment: Close, but not quite. I'm assuming that this function is written in a source file, I'll call `BinAmerPut.R`. I don't suggest you need to put it in a new `.R` file. Assuming RStudio, if you go to *"Session >> New Session"*, it will open a new RStudio window with a new R process. Now, re-`source` your source file (`BinAmerPut.R`) and try to call it as you have above in your question. Note that before you did this, `ls()` should be empty, now contains `BinAmerPut` (func) and `S0`, `R`, `T`, `N`, and `K`, nothing more. You would have seen `object 'sigmaC' not found`.

Comment: Another technique (that I just found while investigating for this discussion): `codetools::findGlobals(BinAmerPut, merge=FALSE)` will show all global `functions` and `variables` on which the function is relying. In my opinion, `variables` should generally be empty (there are always exceptions). In the case of the first definition of your function, it returns `"q"` and `"sigmaC"`.

Comment: @R2evans I tried to code it in R directly and I got no errors :)! Big sigh of relief! Thanks for all your advice and time. Don't worry I didn't take your previous comment in a condescending or "soap-boxing" manner.